# runSCENIC_2_createRegulons(negative values are not allowed in a matrix subscript)

Tags: r

I met the question when I run SCENIC_2_createRegulons,
the error is listed below.

```
runSCENIC_2_createRegulons(scenicOptions,coexMethod=c("top5perTarget"))(I have tried full run 
and all different coexMethod but all methods get the error below)
15:21 Step 2. Identifying regulons
tfModulesSummary:
top5perTarget
98
15:21 RcisTarget: Calculating AUC
Scoring database: [Source file: hg19-500bp-upstream-7species.mc9nr.feather]
15:22 RcisTarget: Adding motif annotation
Number of motifs in the initial enrichment: 21627
Number of motifs annotated to the matching TF: 105
15:22 RcisTarget: Prunning targets
Error in globalMat[coords] :
negative values are not allowed in a matrix subscript
```

I checked the code step one by one.

```
RcisTarget: Prunning targets
dbNames <- getDatabases(scenicOptions)
motifEnrichment_selfMotifs_wGenes <- lapply(names(dbNames), function(motifDbName){
ranking <- importRankings(dbNames[motifDbName], columns=allGenes) addSignificantGenes(resultsTable=motifEnrichment_selfMotifs[motifEnrichment_selfMotifs$motifDb==motifDbName,],
geneSets=tfModules,
rankings=ranking,
 axRank=5000, method="aprox", nCores=nCores)
})
Error in globalMat[coords] :
negative values are not allowed in a matrix subscript
```

The database I used here is 500bp, however, when I used the 10Kb database, everything is fine, I used the same data. I am hoping somebody can help me to fix this problem.